# ¿Por qué el socket se cierra cuando la pantalla del celular se apaga?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy creando un chat con nodejs y socket.io, entonces tengo un evento que desconecta al socket cuando este cierra la pestaña de su navegador. Resulta que hace algunos días estoy desde el celular probando mi aplicación, y cuando la pantalla del celular se apaga, que lo vuelvo a prender, veo que el socket se ha desconectado. Acá dejo el código:

```
socket.on('disconnect', data => {
   if(!socket.nickname) return;
   //io.sockets.emit("nod", data);

   nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickname), 1);
   updateNicknames();
   console.log(socket.nickname + " se ha desconectado");

    });
```

El if valida que el usuario esté conectado. El nicknames.splice() lo que hace es eliminar al usuario de un array en que donde se guardan los usuarios que se conectan (esto es por ahora hasta que incluya la base de datos), la función updateNicknames(); lo que hace es re organizar el array.

¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que sucede?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente eso se debe a los sistemas de ahorro de energía de los dispositivos móviles. De todas formas revísate la configuración en la parte cliente sobre el tema de reconexiones, sin más info no se me ocurren otras opciones.

```
socket = io.connect( 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', {
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayMax : 5000,
    reconnectionAttempts: 99999
} );
```

Lo anterior es un ejemplo de control de reconexión.